# Text inside angular-material switch thumb

Tags: angularjs

I am unable to place text inside the angular-switch by using angular-material. I am using the following tag and I want to insert text inside the switch thumb.

```
 <md-switch class="md-primary" md-no-ink aria-label="Switch No Ink" ng-model="data.cb5"><p>hi</p>
                        </md-switch>
```

In the below image, I need the output like this.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain in more detail about what you want to achieve? What does your data look like, where do you want the text to appear? What have you tried already?

Comment: what is the final output you want exactly ??

Comment: @Sujithrao i need a letter in the switch thumb,I am unable to find the class  md-thumb md-ink-ripple

Comment: swathi i have posted a answer try once

Comment: @Sujithrao ya I tried but it is not getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this might be solve your issue

```
 <md-switch class="inline-label" md-no-ink aria-label="Switch No Ink" ng-model="data.cb5"><p>hi</p> </md-switch>
```

**CSS**

```
md-switch.inline-label .md-bar::before {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 9px;
  line-height: 13px;

  content: "off";
  right: 0;
  padding-right: 3px;      
}

md-switch.inline-label.md-checked .md-bar::before {
  content: "on";
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
md-switch.md-checked .md-thumb:before{
    content: 'on';
    color: white;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```